# Only run next GitHub Actions workflow when previous one is complete

Tags: github, github-actions, webhooks, contentful

Is it possible to only start the next GitHub Actions workflow when the previous one has finished?

We have a site set up that uses Contentful webhooks which triggers a GitHub Actions workflow to build and deploy our site whenever someone publishes/unpublishes something in Contentful.

It works fine if someone only makes one change in Contentful, but if they make multiple changes in Contentful this triggers multiple builds and the site crashes. I'm guessing because we have multiple builds running in parallel.

Is there a way for a build in GitHub Actions to not start until the previous one had finished?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency

Answer (score 2):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) shared in the comment, you can use the `concurrency` configuration to prevent running multiple builds at the same time using GitHub Actions.

> Use concurrency to ensure that only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time. [Reference 1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency) + [Reference 2](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency)

For exemple, if you plan to always cancel the workflows in progress to give priority to the last build, you would use something like the implementation below at the workflow level:

```
concurrency:
    group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
    cancel-in-progress: true
```

The `group` here refers to the workflow name and the branch, which won't allow the same workflow to run more than once for the same reference at the same time.

If you want to avoid running the same workflow for different references as well, the configuration would only need to use `group: ${{ github.workflow }}`.